# Is there a way to add waypoint to existing route for HERE SDK for Android (Premium Edition)

Tags: android, here-api

Let's say we have a route and user want to choose a new point from map and add it to current route what is the best way to do it? Is there some metods in HERE SDK to do this or i need calculate new route for this purpose? If i need to calculate new route how determine by coordinates where new waypoint should be added? Between existing waypoints or it will be last point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, new waypoints need a recalculation. And also insertion point is on you or your users, since this can be pretty anything from new startpoint, new endpoint or whatever you like...